# Jupyter Lab Autocomplete repeats text I've already input

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, autocomplete, jupyter, jupyter-lab

Example: suppose I'm writing `x = df.groupby('column')`. If I've typed `x = df.group` and then hit tab, it autofills to `x = x = df.groupby()` (notice the extra `x =` ).

Another example: if I'm writing `sns.histplot(df.my_column)` and I type `sns.histplot(df.my_c)` and then hit tab, it autofills to `sns.histplot(sns.histplot(df.my_column`

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue `jupyter lab 3.5.2`

Comment: This is not a JupyterLab but a regression in IPython 3.9 and 3.10 which only happens if you have jedi dissabled. You need to upgrade IPython to 3.11